# need help undertanding the strong form of induction

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, induction

I was learning the strong form of induction, and given the following definition:

Sometimes it is necessary to use the following “strong” induction using a “stronger”
(albeit equivalent) hypothesis. For each natural number n, let Pn be a statement.
Suppose that (1) P1 is true and (2) if n is a natural number and if each statement
Pm is true for every m ≤ n, then the statement Pn+1 is also true. Then every single
statement P1, P2, P3, . . . is true. To see this, let M be all the natural numbers such
that Pn is not true. We shall prove that M must be empty, which shows that Pn is
true for every n. Indeed, suppose that M is not empty. Then by well-ordering, M
contains a least element, say n. Since P1 is true, M does not contain 1, so n > 1. Since
1, 2, . . . , n − 1 are not in M (because n is the least element of M), the statements
P1, P2, . . . , Pn−1 must be true. Hence, by Property (2) of the statements, Pn must
also be true. This shows that M does not contain n, which contradicts the assumption
that n is in M. Thus, M must be empty.

which to me it seems like strong form of induction is too strong that Pn could be a nonsense statement and still can be proved follow its way (for example i could let Pn be n = 2n and it seems to me that this still work by its way)  please help me understand why it works and for what range does it works .
thank you so much!

Comment: Can you write out your "proof" that $n=2n$ (or some other incorrect statement) using strong induction?

Comment: @podiki for example i could let Pn be n = 2n and it seems to me that this still work by its way

Comment: P1 is not true as $1\neq 2\cdot1$.

Comment: @podiki but shouldnt by its assumption that p1 is true?

Comment: You need to show that statements (1) and (2) hold and then the conclusion is that $P_n$ is true for all $n$. (1) and (2) are the hypotheses of the theorem. When they are satisfied the conclusion holds.

Comment: @podiki oh，than im just being confused with the words. thank you for helping!